# Facebook login error when app released publicly

Tags: android, facebook

People have been successfully downloading my alpha phase app and logging in with Facebook. I just released it publicly and now people are getting errors logging in. Do I need to change anything to do with my app secret or hash keys once its public instead of in the alpha stage?

Comment: how would facebook know your app is public, for it to function differently ? have u assigned the callback urls correctly ?

Comment: That's a good point. I just know that the app works fine when installed directly on my phone through eclipse and also when downloaded as an alpha tester, but the production apk is causing issues and its the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. its about the hash keys, when you sign an app the hash key is different. 
You can see the error, install your app from the market and see the log from facebook and you can see the error from hashkey.

For example first install your app from the playstore, then conect your cel and see the log when your are trying to logging with facebook, and you can see the next error:

```
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513): Exception during service
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash YDJyZb3zqAYTsk5QiyGsrtNEEvRI does not match any stored key hashes.
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:82)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:161)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:151)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:312)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:142)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:98)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:228)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:436)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:198)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:361)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:58)
07-20 13:07:04.016: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(15513):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:280)
```

as you can see you need to add the key YDJyZb3zqAYTsk5QiyGsrtNEEvRI= (you need to add "=" at the end).

Comment: so the hash key in the error on my phone is the one I should put in the facebook developer hash keys? Mine is 1 character too short in the error message and it won't work. Any ideas?